# cakephp : cookies not create after deleted

Tags: php, javascript, cakephp, cookies

I have a question about cookies in cakephp. I create a cookies in cakephp view successfully, and I wrote a javascript function to delete that cookies if the page reloads, and that function is successfully deleted.
But after that cookies deleted, the same cookies cannot create anymore. Why does this happen?

This is my code that I have used to create that cookies :

```
$isiCookies=$awb['Awb']['id'].'^'.$awb['Awb']['awb_number'].'^'.$companies[$awb['Contract']['company_id']].'^'.$awb['Address']['address'].'^'.$types[$awb['ContractDetail']['content_type_id']].'^'.$awb['Awb']['colie'].'^'.$kilo.'^'.$manifestDetails[$awb['Awb']['id']];
if(!isset($_COOKIE['manifest_courier']))
{
     setcookie("manifest_courier", $isiCookies, $date_of_expiry, "/");
}
else
{
      setcookie("manifest_courier", rawurldecode($_COOKIE['manifest_courier']).'*'.$isiCookies, $date_of_expiry, "/" );
                }
```

And this is the javascript function that I have used to deleted the cookies :

```
$(window).unload(function() {
      Cookies.erase('manifest_courier');  
});
```

Please tell me why the cookies are not created if the page reload. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Delete like `document.cookie="username;expires=" + new Date(0).toGMTString()` in your js. I don't know which method `Cookies.erase` is ?

Comment: Why would you *create* a cookie on page-load and *destroy* on unload? Also, CakePHP has a [`CookieComponent`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/cookie.html) to handle creating cookies.

Comment: Rikesh : this is the code of Cookies.erase: Rikesh : this is the code of Cookies.erase:                                                         erase: function (name) {
  this.create(name,'',-1);
  this[name] = undefined;
 }

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do everything in views.
First off, make sure the Cookie component is included in the controller.

```
var $components = array('Cookie');
```

Then, in your function,

```
$isiCookies = $awb['Awb']['id'].'^'.$awb['Awb']['awb_number'].'^'.$companies[$awb['Contract']['company_id']].'^'.$awb['Address']['address'].'^'.$types[$awb['ContractDetail']['content_type_id']].'^'.$awb['Awb']['colie'].'^'.$kilo.'^'.$manifestDetails[$awb['Awb']['id']]; 

if($this->Session->check('manifest_courier')) 
{
  $this->Cookie->write('manifest_courier',$isiCookies,false,$date_of_expiry);
}else{
  $this->Cookie->write('manifest_courier',rawurldecode($_COOKIE['manifest_courier']).'*'.$isiCookies,false,$date_of_expiry);
}
```

In view, use that Js to delete the cookie if it still exists after refresh.